# Ruby on Rails Solr - Multiple facets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I'm trying to implement facets in a way that when you choose one , all the others don't get canceled so i can have 2 at the same time.

My site has classifieds so for example if i have a classified `"Fender Bass"` , a classified `"Fender Stratocaster"` and a classified `"Gibson Bass"` if i choose the facet `Bass` im able to see both basses but then i'd like to filter deeper and choose `Fender` now if i do that , ill get `"Fender Stratocaster"` and `"Fender Bass"` and the `Bass` facet will not be active , what i intend to do is go from `Bass` deeper to only `"Fender Bass"` when choosing `Fender` after `Bass`

My schema:

```
create_table "classifieds", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "make"
    t.string   "model"
    t.string   "year"
    t.string   "color"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "condition"
    t.string   "price"
    t.string   "offer"
    t.string   "make_country"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_classifieds_on_category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_classifieds_on_user_id"
end
```

My model:

```
class Classified < ApplicationRecord


    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :classified

    has_many :favorite_classifieds, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorited_by , through: :favorite_classifieds , source: :user #for the favorite_by to work :source is needed

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos


    searchable do 
        text :title, :boost => 5
        text :model , :created_month , :make

        time :created_at


        string :created_month   
        string :make    
        string :model
    end

    def created_month 
        created_at.strftime("%B")
    end



end
```

My Controller:

```
def index

    @search = Classified.search do 
        fulltext params[:search]
        with(:created_at)

        facet :model
        with(:model , params[:model]) if params[:model].present?
        facet :make
        with(:make , params[:make]) if params[:make].present?
        facet :created_month
        with(:created_month , params[:month]) if params[:month].present?

    end
    @classified = @search.results

end
```

View.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-9 visible-lg">
        <div class="facets">            

            <h6>Μοντέλο</h6>
            <ul>
                <% for row in @search.facet(:model).rows %>
                    <li>
                    <% if params[:model].blank? %>
                        <%= link_to row.value, :model => row.value %> (<%= row.count %>)
                        <% else %>
                        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :model => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Μάρκα</h6>
            <ul>
                <% for row in @search.facet(:make).rows %>
                    <li>
                    <% if params[:make].blank? %>
                        <%= link_to row.value, :make => row.value %> (<%= row.count %>)
                        <% else %>
                        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :make => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i ended up with this , this works for multiple facets in rails 5!

controller :
def index

```
    @search = Classified.search do 
        paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 10)
        order_by(:created_at , :desc)
        fulltext params[:search]
        with(:created_at)

        active_model = with(:model ,params[:model]) if params[:model].present?

        active_make = with(:make , params[:make]) if params[:make].present?

        active_make_country = with(:make_country , params[:make_country]) if params[:make_country].present?

        active_condition = with(:condition,params[:condition]) if params[:condition].present?

        active_category = with(:cat,params[:cat]) if params[:cat].present?

        facet(:model)   



        facet(:make)            


        facet(:make_country)

        facet(:condition)

        facet(:cat)


        facet :created_month
        with(:created_month , params[:month]) if params[:month].present?

    end
    @classifieds = @search.results

end
```

and in the view :

```
<div class="facets">            


            <h6>Μάρκα</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:make).rows %>
                    <li>
                    <% if params[:make].blank? %>
                        <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:make => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                        <% else %>
                        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :make => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Χώρα Κατασκευής</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:make_country).rows %>
                    <li>
                    <% if params[:make_country].blank? %>
                        <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:make_country => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                        <% else %>
                        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :make_country => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Κατάσταση</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:condition).rows %>
                    <li>
                    <% if params[:condition].blank? %>
                        <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:condition => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                        <% else %>
                        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :condition => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

            <h6>Κατηγορία</h6>
            <ul class="facetlist">
                <% for row in @search.facet(:cat).rows %>
                    <li>
                    <% if params[:cat].blank? %>
                        <%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:cat => row.value).permit!) %> <small class="rowcount"><%= row.count %></small>
                        <% else %>
                        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :cat => nil %>)
                    <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

what happens is that in rails 5 , where you can't `attr_accessor` you have to use `.permit!` at the end of the merge in order to work!

```
<%= link_to(row.value, params.merge(:page  => 1,:cat => row.value).permit!) %>
```

i hope this helps someone else :)